# Unterschied: "an Ort und Stelle sein" vs "vor Ort und Stelle sein"?

Tags: meaning, difference, standard-german

Was ist der Unterschied? Gibt es Unterschied? Wenn gleich, warum braucht man beide Varianten? um die Sprache verwirrender zu machen?

Bitte die Muttersprachler es verständiger zu machen, oder irgendwelche Tipps...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die übliche Redewendung lautet

> *an* Ort und Stelle sein

Sie ist eine Verschmelzung aus den Wendungen

- *an* [einem bestimmten] Ort sein
- *an* [einer bestimmten] Stelle sein

Man beachte, dass in beiden Wendungen die Präposition *an* verwendet wird. Die Redewendung

> *vor* Ort und Stelle sein

halte ich für missglückt, denn sie ist eine Verschmelzung aus den ebenfalls üblichen Redewendungen

- [*vor* Ort](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/vor_Ort) sein
- [*zur* Stelle](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zur%20Stelle%20sein) sein

bei denen sich jedoch die Präpositionen unterscheiden. Es gibt mehrere solcher missglückten Redewendungen, wie „jemand über den Tisch hauen“ oder „[Der Wurf mit dem Zaunpfahl](https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/post-an-den-zwiebelfisch-der-wurf-mit-dem-zaunpfahl-a-353730.html)“ oder „[Licht am Ende des sturmverhangenen Horizonts](https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-licht-am-ende-des-sturmverhangenen-horizonts-a-256341.html)“ (aus *Zwiebelfisch*, spiegel.de).

Comment: Gibt es Unterschied zw "vor Ort sein" und "an Ort sein"? In der Benutzung? Bedeutung? oder Anderem?

Comment: @Capuccinolady, *vor Ort* ist eine feststehende Redewendung, die ausdrückt, dass sich jemand oder etwas an einem ganz bestimmten, meist vorher benannten Ort befindet oder dort ist. Zum Beispiel: „Die Polizei war schnell vor Ort“ oder „Vor Ort gab’s keine Toiletten.“ *An* benutzt man gewöhnlich mit Artikelwort: „Er war nun *an einem* besseren Ort.“ Es ist keine feste Redewendung.

Comment: Bei "zur Stelle" antwortet "zur" auf die Frage "Wohin?" oder "Wo?"?

Comment: @Capuccinolady, in diesem Fall ist *zur Stelle sein* ist eine feste Wendung, nach der man mit *„Wo?“* fragen kann. Anders ist es bei „Die Feuerwehr eilte zur Stelle.“ Hier ist gemeint, dass die Feuerwehr zu einer bestimmten Stelle geeilt ist, nach der man mit *„Wohin?“* fragt.